# Javascript - How to break a looping AnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm writing a small game with canvas in javascript. For that, I use a update function. You can see it here:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//some other code here

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
        circleArray[i].update();

    }

}
animate();
```

And now i want to cancel the AnimationFrame, because i want to send a Text like "YOU WON" but with the update function, that sitll loops, this text will be overwritten.

```
function startGame() {

 //some other code here 

    //OnWin
    this.win = function() {

        window.cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
        //some small style properties here
        ctx.fillText("YOU WON!", width/2, height/2);
    }
//some other code here

}
startGame();
```

I think, that the Animationframe loops, because `cancelAnimationFrame()` will only cancel the frame. But the function still running. I had an idea that i should do it with a boolean but i think that's not a really clear.

Here is my test Bool, but it hasn't worked.:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    win = false;
//some other code here

function animate() {
    if (!win) window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
        circleArray[i].update();

    }

}
animate();


//some code here

function startGame() {
win = false
 //some other code here 

    //OnWin
    this.win = function() {
        win = true
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
        //some small style properties here
        ctx.fillText("YOU WON!", width/2, height/2);
    }
//some other code here

}
startGame();
```

Thanks for every useful help ^^

Comment: You have to assign the `requestAnimationFrame` to a variable and then that variable is the parameter in `cancelAnimationFrame`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame#Examples

Comment: oh. i thougt the requestID is the function that i call. Like  the EventListeners.

Comment: @Gary it works. Thanks ;) A small question. How can i mark this question as solved? Cause here is only your comment.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know.  I don't think you can unless someone submits an answer.